# Having trouble initializing property with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, initialization

I'm using `XLForm`, which has a class `XLFormDescriptor`, which needs to be initialized with `init(title: String)`.

The title I want to use is the return value of my current class's name function (class-level properties aren't a feature yet).

Putting this at a class level, the code to set it up looks like this:

```
let settingsForm = XLFormDescriptor(title: self.name())
```

But this gives the error:

> 'PanelController -> () -> PanelController!' does not have a member
>   named 'name'

Putting this at the top of the class's init call looks like this:

```
let settingsForm: XLFormDescriptor

override init() {
    self.settingsForm = XLFormDescriptor(title: self.dynamicType.name())

    super.init()
}
```

And doing that gives this error:

> 'self' used before super.init call

Putting it after super.init() gives this error:

> Property 'settingsForm' not initialized at super.init call

Any ideas how I can possibly do this?

EDIT: A workaround is to do this:

```
let settingsForm = XLFormDescriptor(title: "")

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.settingsForm = XLFormDescriptor(title: self.dynamicType.name())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift, `self` is not available until all class properties have been initialized. There's a check at compilation time for that.

So if you have a class with properties, inherited from another class:

```
class A {
    var prop1: Int
    init(val1: Int) {
        self.prop1 = val1
    }
}

class B : A {
    var prop2: String
    override int(val1: Int, val2: String) {
        // First initialize properties of this class
        self.prop2 = val2

        // Next call a superclass initializer
        super.init(val1: val1)

        // From now on, you can use 'self'
    }
}
```

you cannot use `self` until *all* (non optional) class properties have been been initialized *and* a superclass initializer has been invoked (if the class is inherited).

If you initialize a property inline, like this:

```
let settingsForm = XLFormDescriptor(title: self.name())
```

you are explicitly using `self` before the class instance has been properly initialized - that's the reason of the compilation error.

The solution you found yourself is not a workaround, but the right way of doing it. You first initialize the property with a value not referencing `self`, then once the class has been initialized, you assign that property a new value.

Note that this is the only case where you are allowed to assign a new value to an immutable property, as long as it is done from within an initializer.

For a better understanding of how initialization works, I recommend reading the corresponding documentation: [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306)